# Por que o atributo bgcolor aceita cores com palavras/nomes/strings aleatórias?

Tags: html, css

Tempos atras li em algum lugar sobre isso, mas nunca entendi o seu funcionamento:
Vejam o exemplo com a palavra `chucknorris`:

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorris"> teste </body>
```

Não só com a palavra `chucknorris` mas qualquer palavra aleatória sempre produz resultados diferentes:

`Earendul` produz amarelo:

```html
<body bgcolor="Earendul"> teste </body>
```

`Fulano` produz vermelho:

```html
<body bgcolor="Fulano"> teste </body>
```

`Mamusca` produz azul:

```html
<body bgcolor="Mamusca"> teste </body>
```

Alguém tem alguma explicação para esse comportamento?

Comment: [E `Gandalf` ciano](http://jsfiddle.net/8oxaaarw/). :)

Comment: Deve ter alguma coisa a ver (há ver) com hexadecimal, pois percebi que colocando 3 letras aleatórias o resultado sempre é preto para mim, e a projeção de cor só vem com alguma letra entre `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`

Comment: Vale notar que o atributo `bgcolor=""` está em desuso/obsoleto: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html, conforme o link: *Os elementos da lista a seguir são totalmente obsoletos e não devem ser usados pelos autores: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isso acontece porque todos os caracteres em falta são interpretados como `0`. Ou seja, `#CC0000` é igual a `#CCXXXX`, o resultado será o mesmo, um vermelho.

Logo, se fizermos isso com a palavra "Earendul" o resultado é `EA0E0D00`, que depois divide-se por 3 parcelas, sendo RGB(Red, Green, Blue). `EA0E0D00` tem 8 caracteres, para ser divisível por 3 tem ser 9. Como eu disse anteriormente, quando falta um caracter adiciona-se um `0`. O resultado final seria: (`EA0`, `E0D`, `000`)

Ou seja, no final basta retirar o excesso, ficando apenas com 2 caracteres por cada parcela:

```
RGB( 0xEA, 0xE0, 0x00) = #EAE000
```

Veja o exemplo:

```html
<!--<body bgcolor="Earendul"> teste </body>-->
<body bgcolor="#EAE000"> teste </body>
```

Comment: Não sabia dessa rsrs, faz total sentido, teste uma palavra que não tenha nenhum caracter #HEX, tipo putim, ele interpreta como se fosse 00000 e a cor fica preta

Answer (score 3):

Esse comportamento tem relação com o parser de atributos legados em navegadores, no caso [`bgcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor), um atributo obsoleto (vide link e [html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)), inclusive nem se recomenda usar esse atributo. A alternativa recomendada é fazer uso do atributo CSS `background-color` que não sofre desse comportamento da pergunta. Veja que o exemplo da pergunta não se aplica quando se usa o CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: chucknorris;
}
```

```html
<body> teste chucknorris não funciona com "background-color"</body>
```

O comportamento apresentado na pergunta não se restringi somente ao texto `chucknorris` ou `esquadraoclasseA` ou `Fulano`, etc. Ele pode ser reaplicado a qualquer texto aleatório. Por exemplo `gandalf`, `melancia`, `graxa`, etc. Veja o exemplo nesta tabela abaixo:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="fulano"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">fulano</td>
    <td bgcolor="esquadraoclasseA"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">esquadraoclasseA</td>
    <td bgcolor="gandalf"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">gandalf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="melancia"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">melancia</td>
    <td bgcolor="graxa"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">graxa</td>
    <td bgcolor="aleatório"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">aleatório</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O que acontece é que os navegadores não conseguem entender o texto informado e o que eles tentam é transformar em algo que entendam, no caso uma *string* em **hexadecimal**, verificando quais caracteres do texto são um [hexadecimal válido](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hexadecimal). Caso seja um hexadecimal válido, mantém, caso contrário, substitui por um zero (`0`).

Vemos pegar de exemplo o texto `esquadraoclasseA` que produz um fundo vermelho no exemplo. O que o navegador vai pensar e fazer é:

1. *O que é esse `esquadraoclasseA`? Não sei.*
2. *Vou tentar converter `esquadraoclasseA` para hexadecimal*
3. *O que é esse `e`? É um hexadecimal válido. Maravilha!*
4. *Agora eu tenho o texto `esquadraoclasseA` ainda.*
5. *Pera ai! O que é esse `s`? Não é um hexadecimal. Vou colocar um `0`*
6. *Agora eu tenho o texto `e0quadraoclasseA`. Opa!*
7. *E por esse caminho eu vou...*
8. *Ufa! Finalmente terminei. Agora eu tenho a string: `e000ad0a0c0a00eA`*
9. *`e000ad0a0c0a00eA` é um hexadecimal válido, mas preciso de um padrão `RGB`*
10. *Vou dividir `e000ad0a0c0a00eA` em 3 seções do `RGB`. Se o tamanho da string não for múltiplo de 3, completo com `0` no fim da string:*

```
`e000ad0a0c0a00eA` => tamanho 16. Preciso completar com `0` até ter 18.
`e000ad0a0c0a00eA00` => tamanho 18.
`e000ad0a0c0a00eA00` => Em 3 seções temos: `R:e000ad G:0a0c0a B:00eA00`.
```

11. *Para cada seção, vou pegar apenas os 2 primeiros valores:*

```
`R:e000ad G:0a0c0a B:00eA00` => `R:e0 G:0a B:00`
```

12. *Agora, vou juntar esses valores: `RGB: e00a00`*
13. *OPA! Finalmente tenho a string `e00a00`, um hexadecimal válido. Vou usar ele `#e00a00` como cor de fundo.*

Logo que cor é esse `#e00a00`? A mesma de `esquadraoclasseA`. Veja no exemplo:

```css
td {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="esquadraoclasseA" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">esquadraoclasseA</td>
    <td bgcolor="#e00a00" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">#e00a00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Vamos replicar esse passao-a-passo para o exemplo `graxa` e ver o resultado final:

1. `graxa` vamos substituir tudo não hexadecimal por `0`
2. Temos `00a0a`
3. O tamanho de `00a0a` é 5 e não é múltiplo e 3. Vou acrescentar mais um `0` para chegar ao tamanho `6`
4. Tenho agora a string `00a0a0`. Vou dividir nas 3 seções do RGB: `R:00 G:a0 B:a0`
5. Vou usar os 2 primeiros dígitos de cada seção para montar o hex da cor
6. Finalmente teremos a string `#00a0a0`

Agora vamos testar a cor `#00a0a0` no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="graxa" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">graxa</td>
    <td bgcolor="#00a0a0" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">#00a0a0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

#### Nota

Essa resposta é baseada nas respostas desta [pergunta do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color), tentando extrair o que eu acho mais interessante de cada uma.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de adicionar o link relevante.